# installing xgboost on Python - channel not found

Tags: python, conda, channel, xgboost, forge

I tried to install xgboost using the following:

```
pip install setuptools
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda install xgboost
```

Received the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current  channels:

  - xgboost

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

setuptools are installed

Not sure what itis not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @umang_gupta - conda install py-xgboost worked perfectly (Win10, Python 3.5)! Thanks!!  Needlees to say one needs conda-forge regardless